# Understanding this nested function to write a table

Tags: ocaml

```
let write_table_channel ch n =
  iter    
    (fun x ->
       iter
         (fun i ->
            output_string ch (string_of_int i);
            output_string ch "\t")
         (map (( * ) x) (numlist n));
       output_string ch "\n")
    (numlist n)
```

This function is a bit confusing, first of all nested functions are overall confusing but mainly if someone could outline in particular what the function is doing this would be very helpful the main issue is the idea of nested functions

Comment: Or at least mark the replies **useful**. And they indeed are.

Answer (score 2):

These are not nested functions but anonymous functions. They are indeed confusing and it is a good style to use nested functions instead. Much like you, I am very confused with this function, so to understand it, I performed a series of simple rewritings. Every time I see a

```
... (fun <args> -> <body>) ...
```

I rewrite it with

```
let somefun <args> = <body> in
... somefun ...
```

In other words, I turn anonymous functions into named functions, and in the process try to give them more meaningful names. Let's do this in a series of steps,
We start with step 0, the initial function,

```
  let write_table_channel ch n =
    iter
      (fun x ->
         iter
           (fun i ->
              output_string ch (string_of_int i);
              output_string ch "\t")
           (map (( * ) x) (numlist n));
         output_string ch "\n")
      (numlist n)
```

Next, we see nested loops iterations, let's pick the outer loop and name it `outer` for starters,

```
  let write_table_channel ch n =
    let outer x =
      iter
        (fun i ->
           output_string ch (string_of_int i);
           output_string ch "\t")
        (map (( * ) x) (numlist n));
      output_string ch "\n" in
    iter outer (numlist n)
```

Now let's extract the inner loop from the outer,

```
  let write_table_channel ch n =
    let inner i =
      output_string ch (string_of_int i);
      output_string ch "\t" in
    let outer x =
      iter inner (map (( * ) x) (numlist n));
      output_string ch "\n" in
    iter outer (numlist n)
```

Now we have small functions that are easy to understand, let's give them meaningful names,

```
  let write_table_channel ch n =
    let print_number i =
      output_string ch (string_of_int i);
      output_string ch "\t" in
    let multiply_by_x_and_print x =
      iter print_number (map (( * ) x) (numlist n));
      output_string ch "\n" in
    iter multiply_by_x_and_print (numlist n)
```

Now it is much easier to read, and, surprisingly not even bigger, the same 8 lines of code!

So what are anonymous functions, also called lambdas, and when they are useful? As their name suggests, anonymous functions are functions that do not have names and are defined in place. They are pretty useful in conjunction with simple (non-nested) iterators, especially when the function itself is small and self-describing, e.g.,

```
let print_ints ch x = 
  List.iter (fun i -> 
   output_string ch (string_of_int i);
   output_string ch "\t") x
```

Since functions in OCaml are curried by default and using the  apply operator `@@`, we can rewrite our function as,

```
  let print_ints ch = List.iter @@ fun i ->
    output_string ch (string_of_int i);
    output_string ch "\t"
```

Notice, that we get rid of the `x` argument and there are no more parentheses.

Comment: Thank you so much ivg same gratitude I gave to Chris goes to you!

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation is important to following flow of code. I have edited the question to fix this.

It may also help to use let bindings to break out functionality. For instance, we can create a local function `print` rather than passing this anonymous function. See the "Naming anonymous functions" section of the [OCaml Programming Guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html).

```
         (fun i ->
            output_string ch (string_of_int i);
            output_string ch "\t")
```

There are also repeated calls to `numList n` which can be factored out.

```
let write_table_channel ch n =

  let print i =
    output_string ch (string_of_int i);
    output_string ch "\t"
  in

  let nums = (numList n) in

  iter    
    (fun x ->
       iter print (map (( * ) x) nums);
       output_string ch "\n")
    nums
```

Hopefully that's easier to digest.

Comment: I did not expect a response thank you so much Chris I was embarrassed to ask, but taking on this language has had many humps on the camel's back shall we say

Comment: Nothing's "intuitive" in the programming world. It's all _learned_. But once you do, OCaml syntax is not bad at all. Between this answer and ivg's, feel free to accept whichever answer you feel best answers your question.